# No name 'Cluster' in module 'cassandra.cluster' in Python (VS Code)

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm struggling with something very basic in Python.
I will be happy if anyone can help me.

I'm working with VS code IDE and I installed cassandra library thru the following command:
"pip install cassandra-driver"
The IDE successfully downloaded and installed. However, when I write in the beginning of the script 'from cassandra.cluster import Cluster', my IDE underlines in red the word "from".
Placing the mouse over the word it shows "No name 'Cluster' in module 'cassandra.cluster' pylint(no-name-in-module)"

Does someone know what is the issue?

Thank you in advance,
Regards

Comment: you need to check that VS Code uses correct Python runtime

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue